# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/fabric/sdk/android/services/common/FirebaseInfo;

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, crashlytics

I'm having issues when trying to run my app in Lollipop, the log is the following:

```
11-08 15:12:35.816 987-987/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.rocketjourney, PID: 987
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/fabric/sdk/android/services/common/FirebaseInfo;
       at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.onCreate(CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:22)
       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696)
       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.FirebaseInfo" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rocketjourney-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.rocketjourney-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

My gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rocketjourney"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 67
        versionName "4.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.rocketjourney.helpers.CustomTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode = true
    }

    dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    ...
```

I have this on my launch activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MultiDex.install(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

when I try to solve this problem, a problem of multiDex appears, so I have no clue what is the main reason why this is appearing since I have tried many solutions but I didn't have luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which solutions did you try?

Comment: can you add your gradle file : is mutidex enabled ?

Comment: Have you got any resolution yet @Jose ?

Answer (score 5):

type `rm -rf .gradle` in your Android Studio Terminal and then try again. That solves it for me!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `build.gradle` contains   `multiDexEnabled: true`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

android {


    defaultConfig {
        ....
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: indeed "multiDexEnabled true" is there

Comment: have you added compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable instant run on your Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android Studio 3.4, gradle plugin version 3.4.0 & distribution version 5.1.1

Faceing above issue.

I have found when disable R8 release build is working means multidex is working.

To Disable R8 put below lines in gradle.properties file.

```
# Disables R8 for Android Library modules only.
android.enableR8.libraries = false
# Disables R8 for all modules.
android.enableR8 = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently; updating Android Studio the the latest (3.5) version, as well as Gradle, Firebase and Fabric solved the issue for me.